# What are the uncontracted forms?

Tags: modal-verbs

> “It’s — all — my — ruddy — fault!” he sobbed, his face in his hands.
>   “I told the evil git how ter get past Fluffy! I told him! It was the
>   only thing he didn’t know, an’ I told him! Yeh could’ve died! All fer
>   a dragon egg! I’ll never drink again! I should be chucked out an’ made
>   ter live as a Muggle!”
>    “Hagrid!” said Harry, shocked to see
>   Hagrid shaking with grief and remorse, great tears leaking down into
>   his beard. “Hagrid, **he’d** (1) have found out somehow, this is
>   Voldemort we’re talking about, **he’d** (2) have found out even if you
>   hadn’t told him.”
>  “Yeh **could’ve** (3) died!” sobbed Hagrid.
>   “An’ don’ say the name!” 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

In (1) and (2) are ‘would’ meaning [OALD #3](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/would), I guess, unlike (3). But I’m not sure of that. Are they as what I’ve guessed or not?

Comment: You're right, they're in consequence clauses of an explicit conditional (*even if...*). (3) is *could have*, past construction of present modal hypothetical *could*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, 1) and 2) are contractions for "he would have" and 3) is for "you could have".